# HttpWebRequest limitation?

Tags: httpwebrequest

I created a COM object that makes a query into a website. It's works perfectly, but when I use this COM object with many threads (50 for example), I get many timeout errors, and I changed the HttpWebRequest timeout to 45 seconds.

How is that possible?

Is there some limitation in this method? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have your code, I could not tell exactly what happened. But this are my assumptions:

- Firstly, You maxed out the default limit number of connections per application to a web host. By default, the number is 2. You can increase it by looking at [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Secondly, the connections were not terminated properly after you transmitted the data. You can verify those HTTP connections by typing **netstat -n** if you're on Windows. Look for connections that have the same destination IP (should be). If this is the case, then you need to properly close the **HttpWebResponse.GetReponseStream()**. This will terminate the HTTP connection quickly.